# What kind of black paint is heat reflective, good for use on glass, and safe for indoor use?

Tags: windows, paint

I'm looking to paint the interior of the glass window of my bedroom with heat reflective black paint. I'm worried that A) whatever kind of paint I get won't be made for adhering to glass, and B) about paint fumes, particularly as my bedroom door must remain shut most of the time. What kind of paint would work for this purpose?

Comment: why not use heat reflective window foil

Comment: Isn't black paint by definition the opposite of reflective? Don't really have an answer otherwise, but speaking from experience, we have tried something like this with styrofoam inside the window, and the glass ended up shattering from the heat. Might be better to apply something to the outside.

Comment: To reflect you usually want something silver or white.  Paint usually sticks quite well to glass, that is why you cover glass or spend hours after scraping the paint off.

Comment: is it dual pane window (double glass)

Comment: As mentioned, foil or silvered plastic is reflective. If you want black, paint **one** surface black, and lose ~1/2 the reflectivity.

Comment: Is "black" really a requirement, or is "opaque" what you're actually after?

Comment: If it's really black it needs to be very glossy.

Comment: Also, if it needs to be black inside, do you really care what color the paint is from the outside? You could always do two layers of paint with a highly reflective white/silver paint facing the exterior followed by an interior layer of black paint.

Comment: The only time you'll have any fumes from _any_ paint is while it's drying. After a few hours, it will be fully dry and the smell will be gone. Open the door _while_ you are painting, then when you're done painting, open the window itself and put a fan in the door, blowing air from the rest of the house into the bedroom. This will help force any smells into the bedroom and out the window. Once the paint is dry remove the fan and resume normal door & window operation. You may have a bit of residual smell for another day or so, but that can be cured by keeping the window open and a fan.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the paint business for 21 years and have never come across heat reflective black paint.

The only thing I know of that comes close is Tex-Cote's heat reflective paint, but I don't see a black. They use a proprietary colorant that claims to be heat reflective. https://www.texcote.com/reflect-tec/reflect-tec-colors/

Maybe give them a call and they can educate. They are located in the US, Florida and California.

Answer (score 0):

Greenhouses reduce the incoming light by using a whitewash. And they don’t do a perfect coat either.

If black was cheaper and worked they would use that.

Which cars are cooler in the car park on a sunny day? Black or white…

Comment: This was flagged (auto or by a user, I don't know) as low quality. While this may all be true, it would probably be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Seeing the same thing, *"This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."* - I'm guessing a bot? And the answer here would be 'whitewash', which is a valid answer imo :)